# Microsoft Dynamics 2010 GP SQL Security

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Migrating an install from server to server. First time I have heard of this application.

It appears that login accounts are SQL server login accounts.
I have migrated the accounts to the new SQL server. Reset a users password to try logging into the application with their account to test but it fails to login.

The SQL SA account is able to login without issues.
What security rights are correct or what allows a user to log into GP?

Comment: How did you migrate the SQL logins to the new server?

Comment: sp_help_revlogin

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I don't know the exact issue but here is my work around.

Reset the System Password

```
UPDATE DYNAMICS..SY02400 SET PASSWORD = 0x00202020202020202020202020202020
```

Access the users

Create a dummy user and copy the access from the target user

delete and recreate the target user and copy access from the dummy user